# Getting ChromeDriver installation failed "end of central directory record signature not found"

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

When I try to run npm install chromedriver I am getting...

```
ChromeDriver installation failed Error extracting archive: Error: end of central directory record signature not found
```

Seems to be similar to [this](https://github.com/frappe/bench/issues/526).

Answer (score 1):

Download chromedriver_win32.zip for required version (in my case it was 2.42.0) from https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/chromedriver

Run command

```
npm install chromedriver --chromedriver_filepath=/path/to/chromedriver_win32.zip -verbose
```

Comment: i have same problem in installing VUE js  and your command solve it , thanks

Answer (score 0):

I received the same issue when I tried to add the following to my .npmrc file:

```
chromedriver_cdnurl=https://myMirror.blah
```

Using the verbose version of npm install, I was able to locate the zip file it was trying to download.

```
npm install -ddd
```

I tried to unzip that file manually and realized that it was empty

```
less zipFileName.zip
unzip zipFileName.zip
```

So I realized that I actually was passing the incorrect URL and I needed to pass the credentials as well for it to download.

```
https://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@MyMirror.blah
```

Not sure your environment, but I needed to point to Artifactory instead of the chromedriver mirror for my environment.

Answer (score 0):

downloading the driver and adding

```
chromedriver_filepath=/home/<user>/path/to/download/zipFilename.zip
```

to your .npmrc will make npm install the downloaded package
see also https://github.com/giggio/node-chromedriver